# LightSlider plugin issue with destroy()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using lightSlider plugin which gets initialized on mouseenter and I need to destroy on mouseleave. Sometimes I get this issue "Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined"

Actually, if you can image I am implementing it on PLP(product listing page) page where there are more than 1 images on the product grid. I have tried various solution available already on StackOverflow but nothing resolved my issue.

```
var slider,
    slider_config = {
    item: 1,
    loop: true,
    pager: false,
    slideMove: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true
}
$('#search-result-items').find('.product-tile-container').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).addClass('slide-active');
        if ($(this).find('#plpimage-slider').children().length > 1) {
            slider = $(this).find('#plpimage-slider').lightSlider(slider_config);
            //slider.goToNextSlide(100);
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('slide-active');
        slider.destroy();
        //$('#plpimage-slider').lightSlider('destroy'); // also tried
        //$('#plpimage-slider').data('lightSlider').destroy(true); // also tried
    }
});
```

This error shows in the browser console. need help so it doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code. Inspect the content of silder. You need also to find a reproduction path.